# Carousel Arrow Key Scroll Not Working

Tags: javascript, carousel, bootstrap-4, slick.js

By default Carousel doesn't have focus on itself when page loads, that's why arrow key scroll in carousel doesn't work unless you interact, but I wanted focus on Carousel and as soon as page loads, I want that arrow key scroll in Carousel is possible.
I tried adding this code :

```
var $carousel = $('.stest');
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        $carousel.slick('slickPrev');
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        $carousel.slick('slickNext');
    }
});
```

I'm Not sure where I went wrong? Need Help !!!

Comment: it seems perfect to me, not sure what is halting you, may you paste more of your code or you may construct a fiddle for us. Thanks

Comment: @LalitSachdeva How to create a JSFiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $carousel.focus();
});
```

Wouldn't something like that focus on carousel on page load?

Comment: No, It doesn't.